# I want a Combobox to immediately update upon adding an entry. Can I use same code as that for datagridview?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I use the following code to update a datagridview immediately upon entering a new entry.

```
Private Sub BindGridAutos()
    Dim constring As String = "server=classified;database=classified"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Autos", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I want to get a combobox to update immediately after adding a new entry, except I only want one column to show up. How can I modify this code to do so!? Thankis!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the table, loop through its rows and add only the column you wish to display:

```
    Dim constring As String = "server=classified;database=classified"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Autos", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)

                    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

                        ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr.Item("ColumnYouWishToDisplay").ToString())

                    Next

                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```